# Reference types which doesnt seem to behave like reference types

Tags: javascript

From what i have read functions and objects are supposed to be reference types in javascript. So if i got an object and in my code, and this object changes, it should immidietly impact all refrences to it. But in below example it doesn't happen:

```
Myobject = {
  key1: 123,
  key2: function() {return this.key1}
}

f = Myobject.key2;

Myobject.key2 = function() {return 'test'};

f();
```

key2 behaves like primitve type by preserving inital state of key2 through its references if it changes. So how exatly this mechanism of data types work in javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = Myobject.key2;
```

What this does is have `f` *point to* the function assigned to `key2` which we'll call the "original function".

```
Myobject.key2 = function() {return 'test'};
```

What this does is have `key2` *point to another function* - an operation that does not affect what `f` is pointing to, which is still the "original function".

Visualization:

```
// key2 = undefined
// f    = undefined

Myobject = {
  key1: 123,
  key2: function() {return this.key1}
}

// key2 = function() {return this.key1}
// f    = undefined

f = Myobject.key2;

// At this point, they point to the same function
// key2 = f = function() {return this.key1}

Myobject.key2 = function() {return 'test'};

// At this point, you changed key2 but f still points to the original function
// key2 = function() {return 'test'};
// f    = function() {return this.key1}

f(); 
// possibly "undefined" because this = window if called this way
// and there's possibly no key1 on window
```